# How do I prevent ctrlp plugin from changing the default spell location?

Tags: spell-checking, plugin-ctrlp

After installing `ctrlp` via pathogen, my default spelling dictionary is located at:

```
~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/spell
```

Instead of its previous location:

```
~/.vim/spell
```

While I can always dig into the root cause and modify the plugin, or symlink the directory, is this normal/intentional?

Comment: Do you have something like `set rtp^=~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/` in your vimrc? If so remove it

Comment: Yes, the instructions here: http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim say to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instructions found at http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim assume you don't have a plugin manager. So it tells you to do the runtime path fiddling yourself (which is an incorrect assumption in this case).

If you read [`:help 'spellfile'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27spellfile%27):

```
When a word is added while this option is empty Vim will set it for
you: Using the first directory in 'runtimepath' that is writable.  If
there is no "spell" directory yet it will be created.
```

You will see that vim uses the first directory that is writable in your runtime path to place the spellfile. The first directory is the ctrlp directory since you used `set rtp^=` to prepend the path to the runtime path.

The first solution would just be to remove the `set rtp^=~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim` line from your vimrc since, that's what pathogen does for you. The second solution would be to change the spellfile with `set spellfile=<absolute_path_to_new_file>`

---

As an FYI, a more up-to-date fork of ctrlp is found at https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim